# how can i connect one single usb disk to two devices（pc）with cable

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB Drive that simultaneously connects to more than one computer](https://superuser.com/questions/161389/usb-drive-that-simultaneously-connects-to-more-than-one-computer)

I have a device with an usb hard key inside,and I want to have an usb update interface used to update the usb hard key outside the device.
i don't know how to do...

Comment: what i think is very simple,like i disconnect the usb cable form my device then connect it to my computer to upgrade.i just don't want to open the device and disconnect the cable every time when i decide to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

What do you call a "hard key"? If it's a hard disk and so that USB device is a storage device: you can't.
You would need a NAS server in your network, able to share the device as shared folder over IP.