# How can I use my computer as a USB storage device?

Tags: linux, usb, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect two Computers with USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/99274/how-to-connect-two-computers-with-usb)

So my TV supports USB and not Ethernet. I don't want to swap USB flash drives everyday. I'd like to plug my always-on Linux computer into it so my TV can access the videos on my computer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Without more info, hard to answer.  If the TV has an Ethernet connection, it might be able to connect to the PC and play video from its storage--post the exact TV brand and model number, along with anything the manufacturer says about using the Ethernet port.

Comment: There is *no Ethernet*.