# Emulate USB flash drive for CNC machine

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

Our CNC machine (Laguna Swift) can only read files from a flash drive. I was wondering if there is a way connect the CNC machine to a Windows 10 computer via USB-A to USB-A cable and share a folder to "emulate" flash drive? Or maybe there is a flash drive that could be accessed by multiple devices at the same time?

[EDIT]
I've followed [this](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive) tutorial and successfully created a network connected flash drive. Other than slow booting it works wonderfully.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's a 13 years old answer, so no, it does not answer my question...

Comment: vanown… it does, you just haven't realised it yet. USB is not a double-ended protocol like ethernet. It has a master [host] at one end & a slave [client] at the other. That's why you can't buy ready-made cables to do this. The answer explains some of the rube goldberg attempts to bypass this restriction; I don't think they really survived.

Comment: Another duplicate: [How to connect two Computers with USB?](https://superuser.com/q/99274/432690)

Comment: Using a Raspberry Pi Zero W you could probably build an appliance that works, because it supports USB OTG.

Comment: Something like SanDisk Connect maybe? looks like it behaves like a USB drive, but can be accessed wirelessly

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this with USB

FAT-32 and ExFAT are not network filesystems, as a result there is no way to have two or more computers accessing them at the same time reliably.

With USB your best options are to build a robot to re-plug the storage media.
(this could just be a bunch of relays switching USB signals)
or to look for a way to connect your device to a network file share.

But seeing as the Laguna controller is a Windows computer,  just jog into that as administrator and set-up the USB drive as a file share, then you can update the files over the network.